# Open HTML Content of PHP file in browser for Website Debug

Tags: php, html, debugging

Whenever I have to test a design change on an HTML page that's written within an PHP file, I have to make the effort of first uploading it to the webpage and then viewing it through the browser. Normally, if it was an HTML file, you'd just update the browser and see the changes locally. Of course, it's not possible to execute PHP on a browser unless you use XAMPP or whatever, but I consider that to be too much for simple debug. Isn't there a way to open a PHP file as just HTML, ignoring all PHP code for debugging purposes? If not, then I'll just get it with XAMPP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have PHP setup in Docker, so that I can run the entire website locally.  The files on my local drive are mounted in the Docker image and I can instantly change code and view the updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in webserver, you can utilize that i guess.

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

If the script does not require the http stack (which i doubt), you could also do:

```
php index.php > index.html
```

Update:

After you executed the command above (php -S), simply type the same url in your browsers address bar.

Comment: I have PHP because I previously installed XAMPP but the php command is not recognized in console